# how to use both AND and OR in same sequelize where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am having a situation to execute a query like :

```
let txt = "test test test"
var array = text.split(' ')

select * from trading_app.symboltables st
where (st.tradingsymbol like '%array[0]%' 
and st.tradingsymbol like '%array[1]%'
and st.tradingsymbol like '%%'
and st.tradingsymbol like '%array[2]%'
and st.tradingsymbol like '%[3]%')
or st.name like '%txt%'
or st.tradingsymbol like '%txt%'
```

how can i create a sequelize where clause with these condtions.

Can someone help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have your and's and or's the wrong way round

Comment: i want to take each word from the input so i split it. And then how can i use it inside sequelize where clause with like. So you are saying that this query is wrong?